# Why is the cell array structure in Matlab not behaving well and keep constructing vectors?

Tags: matlab, data-structures, cell-array

Let's say I have two simple vectors;

```
vec1=[1,2,3];
vec2=[4,5,6];
```

Now I make a cell array from them.

```
cellArray1={vec1,vec2}
```

If I want to create a 2x3 numerical array, it is simple.

```
[vec1;vec2]
%or
[cellArray1{1};cellArray{2}]
```

However, to make a 2x3 cell array from the above, it is not behaving as expected.

```
{vec1(1,:);vex2(1,:)}
{cellArray1{1};cellArray1{2}}
{cellArray1{1}(1,:),cellArray1(1,:)}
```

None give me a 2x3 cell array. Why is that so and how to make a 2x3 cell array containing only the double values in each of its entries in a very formal and efficient way. I don't think using `cell2mat` or writing a code to write another dot m file with `{~,~,~;~,~,~}` which running the resulting new file creates the cell array of interest, are good practices.

Comment: Not only is there not a simple way to do this, but it would be terribly inefficient and expensive. Try this: `a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]; b={1,2,3,4,5,6}; whos` and look at how much memory `a` and `b` occupy. Aren’t you happy MATLAB doesn’t make it easy to convert `a` into `b`? :)

Answer (score 2):

This is by design.

Cell arrays can contain *anything*, and therefore the language is not optimized to interpret that things are the same shape.

if `size(vec1(1,:))` is 1x1 and `size(vex2(1,:))` is 1x50, the following *should* still work (unlike with `[]`).

```
{vec1(1,:);vex2(1,:)}
```

if `cellArray1{1}` is a figure handle and `cellArray1{2}` is a string, the following *should* still work (unlike with `[]`).

```
{cellArray1{1};cellArray1{2}}
```

See first example to know why this *should* work with any shape:

```
{cellArray1{1}(1,:),cellArray1(1,:)}
```

Cell arrays accept many things as input, no problem. So they can not assume that what you are inputing to create the cell is a `1x3` numerical array, and therefore they can not behave as if it were and create a 2x3 cell array. Even if they could check for that and act accordingly, then you would have inconsistent behavior depends on the length of the numerical vector that comes in.

Square brackets can instead actually assume that both vectors are the same size, and error otherwise.

Consider Cell arrays as list that can contain anything in each element, not numerical arrays. If you have stuff that is only numerical arrays, the recommendations is that you use that, vectors/matrices, and not cell arrays.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't `cellArray1{1}(1,:)` mean the entries inside `cellArray1{1}` and not the `cellArray1{1}` itself? If yes, it should be three doubles and not a vector of a three doubles. With brackets, it seems it understands it, but with cell array it seems it doesn't understand that I'm putting only the entries of the vector without its vector-container cover. So it is that I don't know how to call entries of a vector without the vector-container, or the cell array is not well designed and it is bringing back the vector-container without the user's willing.

Comment: @AmirHoseinSadeghimanesh `cellArray1{1}(1,:)` means "from the indexable (lets assume numerical matrix for now) inside `cellArray{1}`, get all elements of the first row". Now, if all of the numerical matrix is just one row, then it is the same as the entire vector. In the same way that for `a=1;`, `a(1)` and `a` are exactly the same thing. "three doubles" and "a vector of three doubles" are the same thing, you can not have three doubles there, hanging alone in a void.

Comment: @AmirHoseinSadeghimanesh The reason why it understands it with brakets its because it makes an assumption: "these two things that I got to concatenate are numerical-like, and are the same length". First assumption comes from the use of `[]` (only those types can be in brackets) and the second one from the fact that numerical-likes have to have one element and you can not have non-square matrices.

Comment: Thanks again. So that was my misunderstanding. In Maple we can use `op(L)` if `L` is a bracket-list to get the entries without their bracket-cover, or using `seq(L[i],i in range)` to get the entries of `L` with the indices in a given range or set and no bracket or list or vector, just the entries themselves. Is there any similar thing in Matlab or Matlab is designed to always wrap things inside a list, vector, etc?

Comment: MATrix LABoratory (MATLAB) was indeed designed with matrices in mind, numerical stuff.  So the core object is a vector/matrix (in fact, even single numbers are vectors/matrices) and that is the most efficient use of the tool. Of course, this was refined 15 years ago and they need to keep adding stuff, so cell arrays are the more complex object that can hold other stuff, for all the toolboxes, graphics, OOP etc they have added. It helps me think of it as matrices/vectors being C arrays, and the other stuff being more complex OOP lists.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to get the data structure that I wanted in the question without using `cell2mat` or a code-file-writing and then running the written code-file.

```
[num2cell(cellArray1{1});num2cell(cellArray1{2})]
% or
vertcat(num2cell(cellArray1{1}),num2cell(cellArray1{2}))
```

Comment: `num2cell(cat(1,cellArray1{:}))` is shorter. But really, you don't want to do this. Don't use a cell array to store scalar values.

Comment: @CrisLuengo sure, my intention is not to use cell-array to store what I can store using a normal array of numbers. The example is not made based on any real example, it is just for the sake of simplicity. :)